# How to Filter a Disconnected Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure, except

I have a main table (Table 1) and I have created another table which is called rangeBefore (Table 2):

```
rangedBefore (Table 2) = 
FILTER (
SUMMARIZE ( 'Campaign Overview', 'Campaign Overview'[campaign],'Campaign Overview'[range_name], 'Campaign Overview'[ranged_flag_in_words] ),
'Campaign Overview'[ranged_flag_in_words] = "RANGED")
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is return the main table but do not show any names which appear in Table 2, but I'm not quite sure how to go about this using DAX.

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Comment: I've shared it, so basically when I filter table 1, and filter table 2 (they aren't currently linked) if a name shows up in Table 2, then that name should not appear in Table 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new measure as follows:

```
Measure Test = 
VAR x = VALUES(rangedBefore[range_name])
VAR y = SELECTEDVALUE('Campaign Overview'[range_name])
RETURN
IF(y in x, 1)
```

Add it to the visual filters on your first table as follows:

[image]